# Passing Enum.class as a parameter?

Tags: java, enums, parameterized

I have an interface `Moded`.  The methods are `getMode()`, `setMode( Enum<?> mode )`.

It also has a method `getMode( Object key )`, which is used to identify the "mode type" in implementing classes when they have multiple modes (e.g. OPEN/CLOSED is one state, but COMMAND_MODE/QUERY_MODE/OTHER_MODE is another state, i.e. "2 dimensions" of mode).

The implementing classes will then use `enums` to provide the possible values of each mode type.

The idea is that `getMode( Object key )` is passed a key which the implementing class uses to identify the mode type to find the value of.  But to make this nicer it would be ideal if you always had to use the `Enum` class object as the key.  You can do this anyway, but to enforce it, I've tried changing to `getMode( Class<Enum<?>> key )`.

For some reason, say I have a class `IndexManager` which implements `Moded`, and it contains an `enum` like this:

```
enum MANAGER_MODE {
    COMMAND_MODE, QUERY_MODE, OTHER_MODE
}
```

and my implemented method looks something like this:

```
@Override
public Enum<?> getMode(Class<Enum<?>> key ) throws Exception {

    if( key.equals( IndexManager.MANAGER_MODE.class )){
        return managerMode;
    }
    ...
```

... and I then try this:

```
indexManager.getMode( IndexManager.MANAGER_MODE.class )
```

I'm getting a message in Eclipse

`The method getMode(Class<Enum<?>>) in the type IndexManager is not applicable for the arguments (Class<IndexManager.MANAGER_MODE>)`

And yet this says "true":

```
String.format( "extends Enum? %s", Enum.class.isAssignableFrom( IndexManager.INDEX_MANAGER_MODE.class ))
```

***Later***

In fact the answer by Andreas is better (no casting; type safety if required).  Using his approach you put

```
<T extends Enum<T>> T getMode(Class<T> key )
```

to allow implementation of multi-mode classes

and

```
<T extends Enum<T>> T getMode()
```

to allow implementation of single-mode classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow the caller to assign the return value to a variable of the given type, you need to replace the wildcards with a template parameter.

E.g. if you want to support this call:

```java
MANAGER_MODE mode = indexManager.getMode( MANAGER_MODE.class );
```

Then your method needs to be like this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Enum<T>> T getMode(Class<T> key) {
    if (key == MANAGER_MODE.class)
        return (T) managerMode;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown mode type: " + key.getName());
}
```

Comment: Actually, can I just ask you about this, because I've tried experimenting with it.  Doesn't this pattern mean that `Moded` has to be parameterised: `Moded<T extends Enum<?>>`?  But given than `Moded` can refer to multiple `Enum` classes this doesn't work.  Otherwise can you show me how the interface method looks and how the implementing class method looks (without compiler complaints)?

Comment: Isn't that what I've already done? Show how `getMode()` would be implemented?

Comment: There is no need for an unchecked operation. You can use `return key.cast(managerMode);` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try `getMode(Class<? extends Enum> key)` instead.

Comment: Sir/Madam, you are a genius of parameterisation.  I take my hat off to you.  Actually I'm putting `getMode( Class<? extends Enum<?>> key )` to avoid a message about "raw types".

Comment: @mikerodent For an explanation of this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p .

Comment: @VGR Tx - will study - I've probably read up on this before, but this sort of not particularly common parameterisation stuff tends to go in one ear and out the other with me.